# How to authenticate with TestRail API?

Tags: rest, http, testrail

I'd like to use the TestRail API, but I am having authentication issues. I setup a Postman to play with the API and query it like:

```
https://my.testrail.io/index.php?/api/v2/get_users
```

I saw another SO question that used the `Authorization` header with basic authentication so I added that:

```
Authorization: Basic myemail@whatever.com:apikey
```

When I tried running this I got:

```
{
    "error": "Authentication failed: invalid or missing user/password or session cookie."
}
```

I've also tried replacing the API key with my password, but that didn't work either. The cURL command generated by Postman is:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://my.testrail.io/index.php?/api/v2/get_users' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic <EMAIL>:<APIKEY>' \
--header 'Cookie: tr_session=<GUID>'
```

I can go to `https://my.testrail.io/index.php?/api/v2/get_users` in my browser after logging in to TestRail and that does work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either add your email/key via "Authorization" tab in Postman or you need to encode them by yourself and put into "Authorization" header (Postman can do it for you when you use "Authorization" tab)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if someone still face this problem (e.g. me).

I've found that you have to press **Save Settings** after adding an API keys

- Not Saved:
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrsRG.png)
- Saved: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpglt.png)